# Creating a boundary around a tiled map

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I've created a tiled map composed of multiple sprite nodes that are 367x367. I create this map like so:

```
for var i = 0; i < Int(multiplier); i++ {
    for var j = 0; j < Int(multiplier); j++ {
        // Positive
        var map = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tiledBackground.png")
        var x = CGFloat(i) * map.size.height
        var y = CGFloat(j) * map.size.height
        map.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
        self.addChild(map)
    }
}
```

In the above example, the multiplier is 27 and the map size is 10,000x10,000.

This creates the map as expected, however I want this map to have boundaries that the player can't leave. I know how to create the boundaries, but I'm not sure what values to initialize the physics body with.
I've tried this: `SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: map.mapSize)` however that produced very erroneous results.

I also tried this: `SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, map.mapSize.width, map.mapSize.height))` which built a physics body like it should (I have showPhysics = TRUE), however the physics body seemed to move with the player (I have the player moving and am centering the map on the player). You can see what I mean here: http://gyazo.com/675477d5dd86984b393b10024341188a (It's a bit hard to see, but that green line is the boundary for the physics body. When the tiled map ends (And where it turns grey), the physics body should stop as that's where the player shouldn't be allowed to move any more).
Just leave a comment if you need any more code (I believe I included anything that is relevant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with a bit of my code I found a fix was to just add the physicsBody to my map instead of the scene. A rather easy fix, so I'm surprised I didn't think of it sooner.
With this in mind, I've answered my own question and no longer need help.